# I have this piece of code, and I would like to put the plots in the same plot in R (like the hold on; function in matlab)

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(womanbed, womanage)
ggplot(data.frame(womanbed, womanage), aes(womanbed,womanage)) + geom_point(color='#56B4E9')

qplot(manbed, manage)
ggplot(data.frame(manbed, manage), aes(manbed,manage)) + geom_point(color='darkblue')`
```

as can you see womanbed,womanage is the first plot and manbed and manage is the second plot. All these vectors are character type (e.g : "24","23"). I want both plots to be at the same figure (so to have dots for men and women with different colors in the same x,y axis)

The data that I have:

womanbed:
"01:00" "23:00" "23:30" "00.30" "23:00" "01:00" "23:00" "02:00" "01.50" "02:00" "01:00" "04:00" "01.30"
"23:30" "00:00" "00:00" "01:00" "00:00" "00:30" "01:56" "05:30" "23:45" "00:45" "22.40" "02:00" "00:15"
"00:30" "23:00" "22:00" "00:00" "22:00" "00:10" "23:00"

manbed:
"01:00" "10:30" "00:30" "01:02" "02:00" "03:00" "23:00" "00:00" "23:30" "00:00" "23:40" "23:45" "02:00"
"02:00" "12:00" "01:00" "23:30" "01:15" "23:30" "01:00" "01:00" "01.30" "01:30" "01:57" "23:00" "23:00"
"00:06" "08:00" "02:00" "22.30" "02:30" "22:15" "00:30" "02:00" "23:30" "23:59" "23:00" "01:00" "01:00"
"23:30" "01:30" "23:00" "03:00" "22.30" "01:30" "23:00" "00:15" "23:05" "23:00" "01:45" "01:00" "02:00"
 "23:00" "00:00" "12:00" "03:00" "23:00" "11:55" "02:00" "03:00" "05:00" "02:00" "11:00" "15:55" "23:59"
"02:00" "03:00" "06:00" "22:45" "04:00" "22:30" "00:30" "00:00" "01:45" "01:45" "22.30" "01:00" "01:00"
"22.45" "12:00"

manage:
"26" "27" "26" "47" "26" "27" "27" "23" "23" "36" "27" "25" "23" "24" "28" "25" "23" "23" "23" "25" "24"
 "26" "25" "25" "23" "22" "27" "23" "22" "26" "27" "37" "22" "23" "25" "24" "26" "23" "26" "22" "24" "27"
 "23" "27" "24" "25" "22" "25" "25" "23" "28" "24" "27" "23" "28" "28" "37" "26" "27" "24" "25" "23" "28"
"25" "27" "30" "24" "23" "23" "25" "26" "27" "23" "21" "21" "25" "24" "26" "24" "25"

womanage:

"27" "22" "24" "23" "23" "25" "29" "24" "27" "22" "24" "25" "28" "24" "17" "26" "24" "25" "22" "23" "28"
 "22" "22" "27" "25" "24" "22" "22" "23" "23" "34" "23" "24"

All the 4 variables are character vectors.

I want a plot like this:[run the code to see], that has x axis for the bed times, and y ages for the ages for both woman and man (with different colours for each gender)

Comment: Please post example data. But still... 
What you probably want is "facets" (eg., `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`).

Comment: I want to diagrams one top of the other. So one plot with two diagrams

Comment: Then please post example data.

Comment: You'd probably be best off combing your data into one dataframe, with columns `gender`, `bed`, `age` and using `aes(group = gender)`. That will put all your data on one plot, separating the genders by color.

Comment: @PoGibas description updated :) I added the exact data that I have and I want to plot for both woman and men (in seperate colours) what I have done using the code that I posted. Thanks

Comment: @kostakis done. Please let me know if there is something missing :)

Comment: I have these errors:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmuf44phygn5rra/see.png?dl=0
@PoGibas
And I can not see all the values in the plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
### Load packages
# Preferred (imo) way to handle table
library(data.table)
# Best plotting package
library(ggplot2)
# Time format related stuff
library(lubridate)

### Prepare data
wb <- c("01:00", "23:00", "23:30")
mb <- c("01:00", "10:30", "00:30")
# Convert to time scale
wb <- hm(wb)
mb <- hm(mb)
wa <- c("27", "22", "24")
ma <- c("26", "27", "26")
# Convert character to numbers
wa <- as.numeric(wa)    
ma <- as.numeric(ma)
# Create data table
dWomen <- data.table(bed = wb,
                     age = wa,
                     gender = rep("Women", length(wa)))
dMen <- data.table(bed = mb, 
                   age = ma,
                   gender = rep("Men", length(ma)))
# Merge women and men datasets into one
dPlot <- rbind(dWomen, dMen)

### Final plot
ggplot(dPlot, aes(bed, age, color = gender)) +
    geom_point(size = 2) +
    scale_x_time() +
    labs(x = "Hours", y = "Age", 
         title = "Hours ~ Age, per gender") +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1", 
                       name = "Gender")
```

**Edit:** If there is preference for other colour palette one can use `scale_colour_manual` instead of `scale_color_brewer`.

[image: ResultPlot]

Comment: Hey, I tried to implemented but I can not use the following package:
installed.packages("data.table")
     Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use
     OS_type Archs MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built

Comment: O sorry I found the mistake, wait a second now

Comment: I have these errors: dropbox.com/s/nmuf44phygn5rra/see.png?dl=0 @PoGibas And I can not see all the values in the plot

Comment: @kostakis do `age` and `bed` vectors have the same length? If they do, please check `bed` vector - do all entries have the same structure (ie., `hour:minute`).

Comment: length(manage)=length(manbed) and length(womanage)=length(womanbed)
but length(manage) is not equal to length(womanage)

Comment: Can you please post: `head(dMean)` and `head(dWomen)`